# Doesn't get past .load jQuery line in 'django-bootstrap-modal-forms' plugin code, Create View form in modal

Tags: python, jquery, html, django, bootstrap-4

I'm not familiar with javascript but I've been commenting out this js plugin, made for django projects, and using .modal("show") as a signifier for when the code actually had executed - and I cannot see why this doesn't show the modal (meaning it never got past the load statement).

modal_forms.js

```
(function ($) {
// Open modal & load the form at formURL to the modalContent element
var newForm = function (modalID, modalContent, modalForm, formURL, errorClass, submitBtn) {
##IT WOULD SHOW MODAL IF SCRIPT HERE##
    $(modalContent).load(formURL, function () {
        $(modalID).modal("show");
        ##DESIGNED TO SHOW HERE BUT DOESNT##
        $(modalForm).attr("action", formURL);
        // Add click listener to the submitBtn
        ajaxSubmit(modalID, modalContent, modalForm, formURL, errorClass, submitBtn);
    });
};

// Add click listener to the submitBtn
var ajaxSubmit = function (modalID, modalContent, modalForm, formURL, errorClass, submitBtn) {
...};

// Check if form.is_valid()
var isFormValid = function (modalID, modalContent, modalForm, formURL, errorClass) {
...};

$.fn.modalForm = function (options) {
    // Default settings
    var defaults = {
        modalID: "#modal",
        modalContent: ".modal-content",
        modalForm: ".modal-content form",
        formURL: null,
        errorClass: ".invalid",
        submitBtn: ".submit-btn"
    };

    // Extend default settings with provided options
    var settings = $.extend(defaults, options);

    return this.each(function () {
        // Add click listener to the element with attached modalForm
        $(this).click(function (event) {
            // Instantiate new modalForm in modal
            newForm(settings.modalID,
                settings.modalContent,
                settings.modalForm,
                settings.formURL,
                settings.errorClass,
                settings.submitBtn);
        });
    });
};

}(jQuery));
```

This is referenced in my base template that would be extended by other templates that make up the body content and not just the navigation bar. The sections highlighted show the button that will trigger the modalForm function, an empty modal form and at the bottom the js script that links the trigger and the modalForm function.

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    {% load staticfiles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/> <!--bootstrap css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'WebProjects/style.css' %}"/> <!--style file-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> <!--icons-->
    {% block head %}{% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'webprojects:index' %}">ProjectOverview<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                <li class="nav-item active">
            <!-- Creating a new project, Pop up trigger -->
                    <button class="create-project btn btn-primary" type="button" name="button" id="modalTrigger"> <!--class="nav-link ml-sm-1" href="#"-->
                        <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> AddProject <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                    </button>
            </ul>

            <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modal">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content" id="modalContent"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

    ...
        </div>
    </nav>

    {% block body %}{% endblock %}

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script> <!-- Refrencing js assets and bootstrap -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- jQuery plugins found unsuitable, Reverse engineered and modified version found bellow -->
    <script src="{% static 'WebProjects/js/modal_forms.js' %}"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#modalTrigger").modalForm({
                formURL: "{% url 'webprojects:create_projects' %}"
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The complexity of this is that instead of just a static form in the modal, it is meant to load the form that would only be generated at the view that the URL is linked with - without leaving the page.

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'webprojects'
urlpatterns = [
    # /projects/
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    # /projects/-/create
    path('create', views.ProjectsCreateView.as_view(), name='create_projects')
]
```

views.py

```
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView  # UpdateView, DeleteView
from .mixins import PassRequestMixin


from .models import Projects
from .forms import ProjectsForm


class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'WebProjects/index.html'
    queryset = Projects.objects.all()  # pylint: disable=E1101


class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Projects
    template_name = 'WebProjects/detail.html'


class ProjectsCreateView(PassRequestMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = ProjectsForm
    template_name = 'WebProjects/create_projects.html'
    success_message = "Success"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Projects
from .mixins import PopRequestMixin, CreateUpdateAjaxMixin


class ProjectsForm(PopRequestMixin, CreateUpdateAjaxMixin, forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Projects
        fields = ['project', 'description']
```

Another part of django-bootstrap-modal-forms is the mixins used in these two files.
mixins.py

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import (REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, get_user_model, login as auth_login)
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect


class PassRequestMixin(object):
    """
    Mixin which puts the request into the form's kwargs.
    Note: Using this mixin requires you to pop the `request` kwarg
    out of the dict in the super of your form's `__init__`.
    """
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(PassRequestMixin, self).get_form_kwargs()
        # Update the existing form kwargs dict with the request's user.
        kwargs.update({"request": self.request})
        return kwargs


class PopRequestMixin(object):
    """
    Mixin which pops request out of the kwargs and attaches it to the form's
    instance.
    Note: This mixin must precede forms.ModelForm/forms.Form. The form is not
    expecting these kwargs to be passed in, so they must be popped off before
    anything else is done.
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop("request", None)
        super(PopRequestMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class CreateUpdateAjaxMixin(object):
    """
    Mixin which passes or saves object based on request type.
    """
    def save(self, commit=True):
        if not self.request.is_ajax():
            instance = super(CreateUpdateAjaxMixin, self).save(commit=commit)
        else:
            instance = super(CreateUpdateAjaxMixin, self).save(commit=False)
        return instance
```

I've focussed on experimenting with the html and js rather than the python back-end but only because I have confidence that it is not the cause of the problem - unless the way I have the back end is simply not suited for how the load function is intended to be used. 
I do hope I'm simply making a small mistake, any creative suggestions appreciated xoxo

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Share the only RELEVANT code snippets in order to track down  your issue.

Comment: Due to django's structure, each of one these files is passed in creating the correct output, the bug may lie in one of these - Sorry, I already tried to cut out parts. The part I tried pushing most attention to is the .load statement.